# self.register giving attribute error

Tags: python, attributes, tkinter

The following code is giving 'Daily Order Object' has no attribute 'register'. I have no idea why this would be - any help gladly accepted.

I am trying to validate the Entry widget and am trying to use what I thought was a universal method .register() to do register a function "is_valid_int()" that would check that the Entry widget contains an integer.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *

class DailyOrderGUI:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        #Data entring frame
        self.frame = Frame(parent, bg = "grey")
        self.frame.grid(row=0)
        self.label1 = Label(self.frame, text = "Mrs CackleBerry's Egg Ordering System", bg="grey", font=("Comic Sans MS", "14", "bold"))
        self.label1.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.v = StringVar()
        self.v.set("Monday")
        self.label2 = Label(self.frame, text = "Which day are you ordering for?", bg="grey", font=("Arial", "12", "bold"))
        self.label2.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 4, sticky = W)
        self.rb1 = Radiobutton(self.frame, variable = self.v, bg="grey", value = "Monday", text = "Monday")
        self.rb1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.rb2 = Radiobutton(self.frame, variable = self.v, bg="grey", value = "Tuesday", text = "Tuesday")
        self.rb2.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)
        self.rb3 = Radiobutton(self.frame, variable = self.v, bg="grey", value = "Wednesday", text = "Wednesday")
        self.rb3.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = W)
        self.rb4 = Radiobutton(self.frame, variable = self.v, bg="grey", value = "Thursday", text = "Thursday")
        self.rb4.grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky = W)
        self.rb5 = Radiobutton(self.frame, variable = self.v, bg="grey", value = "Friday", text = "Friday")
        self.rb5.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.rb6 = Radiobutton(self.frame, variable = self.v, bg="grey", value = "Saturday", text = "Saturday")
        self.rb6.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)
        self.rb7 = Radiobutton(self.frame, variable = self.v, bg="grey", value = "Sunday", text = "Sunday")
        self.rb7.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = W)
        self.label3 = Label(self.frame, text = "Customer's Name:?(Press \"Orders Complete\" to finish)", bg="grey", font=("Arial", "12", "bold"))
        self.label3.grid(row = 4, columnspan = 4,padx = 5,sticky = W)
        self.e1 = Entry(self.frame, width = 30)
        self.e1.grid(row = 5, columnspan = 4, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady=3)
        self.e1.focus()
        self.label4 = Label(self.frame, text = "How many eggs being ordered:?", bg="grey", font=("Arial", "12", "bold"))
        self.label4.grid(row = 6, columnspan = 4,padx = 5,sticky = W)
        vcmd = (self.register(self.is_valid_int),"%P")
        self.e2 = Entry(self.frame, width = 10, validate='all', validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.e2.grid(row = 7, columnspan = 4, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady=3)
        self.e2.bind("<Return>", self.get_orders)

        self.btn1 = Button(self.frame, text = "Submit")
        self.btn1.grid(row = 8, padx = 5, sticky = E+W)
        self.btn1.bind("<Button-1>", self.get_orders)
        self.btn2 = Button(self.frame, text = "Orders Complete", command = self.show_summary_result)
        self.btn2.grid(row = 8, column = 3, padx = 5, sticky = E+W)

        #Summary Frame
        self.summ_frame = Frame(parent, bg = "grey")
        self.summ_frame.grid(row=0)
        self.summ_label1 = Label(self.summ_frame, text = "Mrs CackleBerry's Egg Ordering System", bg="grey", font=("Comic Sans MS", "14", "bold"))
        self.summ_label1.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.scrolled_display = ScrolledText(self.summ_frame, width = 50, height = 10, bg="thistle", font=("Times New Roman", "12"))
        self.scrolled_display.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 2, padx = 5, pady = 20, sticky = W)
        self.data_entry_btn = Button(self.summ_frame, text = "Back to Data Entry", command = self.show_data_entry_frame)
        self.data_entry_btn.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = SE, padx = 5, pady = 20)

        self.egg_orders=[]

        self.show_data_entry_frame()

    def is_valid_int(self, txt):
        # txt - value in %P

        if not txt:         # accept empty string
            return True

        try:
            int(txt)
            return True     # accept integer

        except ValueError:  # not an integer
            return False

    def invalid_int(self, widgetName):
            # called automatically when the
            # validation command returns 'False'

            # get entry widget
            widget = self.nametowidget(widgetName)

            # clear entry
            widget.delete(0, END)

            # return focus to integer entry
            widget.focus_set()
            widget.bell()

    def show_data_entry_frame(self):
        self.summ_frame.grid_remove()
        self.frame.grid()
        root.update_idletasks()

    def show_summary_result(self):
        self.frame.grid_remove()
        self.summ_frame.grid()
        root.update_idletasks()
        self.scrolled_display.delete('1.0', END)
        if len(self.egg_orders) == 0:
            self.scrolled_display.insert(END, "No Orders")
        else:
            total = 0
            self.scrolled_display.insert(END, "Orders for " + self.v.get() + "\n")
            for i in range(len(self.egg_orders)):
                total += self.egg_orders[i].num_eggs
                self.scrolled_display.insert(END, str(self.egg_orders[i]) + "\n")
            self.scrolled_display.insert(END, "" + "\n")
            self.scrolled_display.insert(END, "Summary for " + self.v.get() + "\n")
            self.scrolled_display.insert(END, "" + "\n")
            self.scrolled_display.insert(END, "Total eggs: " + str(total) + "\n")
            self.scrolled_display.insert(END, "Dozens required: " + str(self.get_dozens(total)) + "\n")
            average = 0
            if len(self.egg_orders) > 0:
                average = total / len(self.egg_orders)
            self.scrolled_display.insert(END, "Average number of eggs per customer: {0:.1f}".format(average) + "\n")

    def get_orders(self, event):
        """
        Collects order information - name, number of eggs in a loop
        """
        self.name = self.e1.get()
        self.no_eggs = self.e2.get()
        self.e1.delete(0, END)
        self.e2.delete(0, END)
        self.e1.focus()
        self.egg_orders.append(EggOrder(self.name, self.no_eggs))

    def get_dozens (self, total):
        """
        returns whole number of dozens required to meet required number of eggs
        """
        num_dozens = total//12
        if total%12 != 0:
            num_dozens += 1
        return num_dozens

class EggOrder:

    price_per_doz = 6.5
    def __init__(self, name, num_eggs):
        self.name = name
        self.num_eggs = int(num_eggs)


    def calc_price(self):
        self.price = EggOrder.price_per_doz/12 * self.num_eggs
        return self.price

    def __str__(self):
        return("{} ordered {} eggs. The price is ${:.2f}".format(self.name, self.num_eggs , self.calc_price()))



#main routine
if __name__== "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Mrs Cackleberry's Egg Ordering Program")
    frames = DailyOrderGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

your class DailyOrderGUI: doesn't implement nor inherit method register.

Propobly you need inherit it form other widget

Comment: I thought the register method was built into tkinter or python. Is this not the case?

Comment: Found the answer. You need to register the validate command the the child level at which it is being called i.e.vcmd = (self.register(self.is_valid_int),"%P") should be changed to vcmd = (self.frame.register(self.is_valid_int),"%P")

Comment: Yes, 'register' is not built into default 'object' in python. In this case this is a part of tkinter library, so you have to inherite it or use from tkinter object, like you did.